# iPad 2 screen unresponsive in top half

Tags: ipad, screen, repair

I have an iPad 2 that I got for free that I’m going to fix up (digitizer) and give to my nephew. Before I fix it I was sorting out what I would have to do for it, and I noticed while in portrait mode the to half of the screen cannot be clicked or touched. Would I need another part or just the digitizer? I plan on fixing this thing no matter what so please don't just rant about how useless iPad 2s are. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I’m not mistaken, the LCD and digitizer are glued together, so you’d need an entire screen assembly.

Comment: The kit I have recommends using a heat in to separate from the glue and videos I’ve seen from professional repairs use heat guns too

Comment: If you have info to that level, I’m not sure what the question is.  You need a digitizer; they don’t come in “top and bottom halves.”